# How to sort a list of numbers that with fixed prefix?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of `['rs12345','rs21','rs55189']`;
I need to sort them as numbers after strip the prefix `'rs'`.

How can I do it in Python ?

```py
# row.keys() is ['rs12345','rs21','rs55189']
fieldnames = sorted(list(row.keys()),key=itemgetter(slice(2, None)))
```

This code will not working after add `int(''.join(xxx))`.

And the dict `row` is a generator so I have to put it into `list()` to get its values.

---

```
_fieldnames = list(row.keys())
_fieldnames.remove(sidname)
_fieldnames = sorted(_fieldnames, key=lambda i: int(i[2:]))
```

Got it working.
I forgot that I have to remove sampleid, which contains no `^rs`,  first.

Comment: `key=lambda i: int(i[2:])`

Comment: Is there and thing like "$_" in Perl to be put into `i` ?

Comment: Is this a question about Perl, or Python?

Comment: Note that you might also simply consider a [natsort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4836710/476).

Comment: The suggested duplicate question has accepted answer: *"use `.split('_')[1]` to separate the prefix from the number"*. But that doesn't apply here, since there is no `'_'` character in the strings...

Comment: @Stef No, it's not an *exact* solution, but it illustrates the correct approach (which `itemgetter(slice ...)` is simply not). We do expect a *bit* of work to be done to adjust to the situation as necessary. And nevertheless, I posted the exact solution as the first comment.

Comment: @deceze Yes, I find your code is ready to work. I forgot to exclude the first element before sort.